# How to update the object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to update/merge the object with key and id using javascript.

I have array objects `list` and `obj_trans, obj_fund`, need to override/update the key value using javascript.

In `list` obj , id `trans` should be updated with the `obj_trans` key value.
In `list` obj , id `fund` should be updated with the `obj_fund` key value.

```
console.log("result:", updateObj(list, obj_trans););

function updateObj(list, obj_trans){
  let filtertrans= list.filter(e=>e.id==obj_trans[0].id);
  let res =  Object.assign({}, filtertrans, obj_trans);
  return res;
}


var list=[{
  "id": "trans",
  "fee": 2,
  "amount": 100,
  "rate": 0.2
},{
  "id": "fund",
  "fee": 3,
  "amount": 200,
  "rate": 0.4 
},{
  "id": "insta",
  "fee": 2,
  "amount":  250,
  "rate": 0.1
}]

var obj_trans=[{
  "id": "trans",
  "fee": 1,
  "amount": 300,
  "rate": 0.2,
  "netfee": "3",
  "option": "credit"  
}]
var obj_fund=[{
  "id": "fund",
  "fee": 3,
  "amount": 400,
  "rate": 0.5 
  "netfee": "2",  
}]


ExpectedOutput:

result: [{
  "id": "trans",
  "fee": 1,
  "amount": 300,
  "rate": 0.2,
  "netfee": "3",
  "option": "credit" 
}{
  "id": "fund",
  "fee": 3,
  "amount": 400,
  "rate": 0.5 
  "netfee": "2", 
},{
  "id": "insta",
  "fee": 2,
  "amount":  250,
  "rate": 0.1
}]
```

Comment: the ExpectedOutput, result, the second element is not correct? Should be same as obj_fund?

Comment: @miyavv isn't your function already does it for the trans? Do you want to create a function that can handle all 3 (trans, fund, insta)?

Comment: @GlenK thanks for reply, but its not working for trans and yes want to handle function for all 3 (trans, fund, insta)

Comment: @miyavv i got { id: "trans", fee: 1, amount: 300, rate: 0.2, netfee: "3", option: "credit" } when using a refined version of your code function: updateObj(list, obj_trans){
  let filtertrans = list.filter(e => e.id === obj_trans[0].id);
  let res =  Object.assign({}, filtertrans, obj_trans);
  return res;
}

Comment: @miyavv so if the data is exactly like that, what you need is to add more params to the function function updateObj(list, obj_trans, obj_fund){}; and use and if else clause within that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, I think this is what you want:

```
function mergeList(sourceArray, ...newArrays) {
  const unitedArray = newArrays.flat() // or  newArrays.reduce((p, c) => p.push(c), [])
  return sourceArray.map( ele =>  unitedArray.find( ({id}) => id === ele.id ) || ele )
}
console.log(mergeList(list, obj_trans, obj_fund))
```

If you want to update the origin list, then

```
list = mergeList(list, obj_trans, obj_fund)
```

Note:
You can add more element in the function, like

```
mergeList(list, obj_trans, obj_fund, obj_A, obj_B, obj_C)
```

Comment: I think you are not merging the list object with obj_trans and obj_fund, you are just replacing. For example if a list object with id "trans" contains a property "abc:0.5", it would not be in the result set as per your code.

Comment: Yes, it really depends on the use case. I am not sure if the origin value is needed or not. If yes, then `  return sourceArray.map( ele =>  ({ ...ele, ...unitedArray.find( ({id}) => id === ele.id }) )`

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted solution would not merge the list object with the objects obj_trans and obj_fund, It just replaces. So I just modified the above solution provided by 'NCM'. Now the properties which are there in list object but not in "obj_trans" or "obj_fund" would be retained in the result.

```
 function mergeList(sourceArray, ...newArrays) {
   const unitedArray = newArrays.flat() 
   return sourceArray.map( ele =>  
        Object.assign({}, ele, unitedArray.find( ({id}) => id === ele.id )) || ele )
 }
 console.log(mergeList(list, obj_trans, obj_fund))
```

Comment: I add a comment to my answer. It really depends on the use case. But in your ans, `|| ele` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/). This is also prevent `list` object another key value.

```js
var list=[{
  "id": "trans",
  "fee": 2,
  "amount": 100,
  "rate": 0.2
},{
  "id": "fund",
  "fee": 3,
  "amount": 200,
  "rate": 0.4,
  "test": 10
},{
  "id": "insta",
  "fee": 2,
  "amount":  250,
  "rate": 0.1
}]

var obj_trans=[{
  "id": "trans",
  "fee": 1,
  "amount": 300,
  "rate": 0.2,
  "netfee": "3",
  "option": "credit"  
}]

var obj_fund=[{
  "id": "fund",
  "fee": 3,
  "amount": 400,
  "rate": 0.5,
  "netfee": "2"
}]

function updateObj(list, ...args)
{
 if (typeof list == "object") {
     args = args.flat();
     list.filter(function(value, index) {
          var append = args.find(x => x.id == value.id) || value;
            // Merge two objects.
            list[index] = $.extend(true, {}, value, append);
        });
    }
    return list;
}

var updatedList = updateObj(list, obj_trans, obj_fund);
console.log(updatedList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```